# Postgresql how to change int4range to numrange column type

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to change column from int4range to numrange but I get an error.

```
ALTER TABLE tb_investment_options 
    ALTER COLUMN c_investment_options_size_pk 
          TYPE numrange USING c_investment_options_size_pk::numrange
```

What would be the correct query?

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: Typ int4range can not be changed to Typ numrange

Answer (score 0):

This will work, you take lower and upper bound of range and use them as parameters in function that creates numrange:

```
ALTER TABLE tb_investment_options
ALTER COLUMN c_investment_options_size_pk
TYPE numrange
USING numrange(lower(c_investment_options_size_pk), upper(c_investment_options_size_pk));
```